# Getting List of Model1 with List of Model2 in it LINQ - MVC 4 EntityFramework 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I have a requirement where I need to get a List of Model1 (List) using Linq, the Model1 have List of Model2 (List) in it and I need to fetch that also. For this I have created a Linq but m getting following error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1 [OurCourse]
>   ToList[OurCourse](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
>   [OurCourse])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a
>   store expression.

Please refer below for detail:

1. I have two tables Colleges and Courses, with following columns:
   College: ID, Name, Contact, City, Address

   Cource: ID, CollegeID, Name, Years
2. My project have two view models for them, as follows:

   ```
   public class OurCollege
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public string Contact { get; set; }

       public List<OurCourse> MyCourses { get; set; }
   }

   public class OurCourse
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }

       public int NumberOfYears { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Here the the query query which I have prepared but I am getting the error:

   ```
   var colleges = db.Colleges
                    .Select(cld => new OurCollege()
                     {
                         Name = cld.Name,
                         Contact = cld.Contact,
                         MyCourses = cld.Course
                                        .Select(crs => new OurCourse()
                                        {
                                            Name = crs.Name,
                                            NumberOfYears = crs.Years
                                        }).ToList()
                      }).ToList();
   ```

Comment: What happens if you remove the `ToList()` call for courses?

Comment: I get this error : "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Genetic.IEnumrable<OurCourse>' to 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Genetic.List<OurCourse>'. An emplicit conversation exists (are you missing a cast)"

   and when I do " MyCourses = (List<OurCourse>)cld.Course .... " then I get this error : "Unable to cast the type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Answer (score 0):

How about doing like this:

```
MyCourses = from crs in cld.Course
            select new OurCourse
            {
               Name = crs.Name,
               NumberOfYears = crs.Years
            }
```

Your complete query will look now:

```
var colleges = db.Colleges
                 .Select(cld => new OurCollege()
                  {
                      Name = cld.Name,
                      Contact = cld.Contact,
                      MyCourses = (from crs in cld.Course
                                  select new OurCourse
                                  {
                                    Name = crs.Name,
                                    NumberOfYears = crs.Years
                                  }).ToList()    
                   }).ToList();
```

Actually **LINQ to Entities**  converts your query into SQL.It doesn't know how to translate `ToList()` in **SQL**

An alternate is to change you `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>` and remove `ToList()` frim your original code:

```
public IEnumerable<OurCourse> MyCourses { get; set; }
```

and in query:

```
var colleges = db.Colleges
                 .Select(cld => new OurCollege()
                  {
                      Name = cld.Name,
                      Contact = cld.Contact,
                      MyCourses = cld.Course
                                     .Select(crs => new OurCourse()
                                     {
                                         Name = crs.Name,
                                         NumberOfYears = crs.Years
                                     })
                   }).ToList();
```

For more details visit this [**Entity Framework ToList() in nested type (LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method)**](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/entity-framework-tolist-in-nested-type-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method/)

Comment: tried this, getting "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Genetic.IEnumrable<OurCourse>' to 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collection.Genetic.List<OurCourse>'. An emplicit conversation exists (are you missing a cast)"

Comment: tried that too :( .. the error mentioned in my question .. I am getting that. .. I am referring the link you shared

Answer (score 0):

A foreach loop will work, you can write the query something like this

```
var colleges =   db.Colleges
                   .Select(x => new OurCollege()
                   {
                        CollegeId = x.CollegeId,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        Contact = x.Contact
                   }).ToList();

foreach (var college in colleges)
{
        college.MyCourse =  db.Course.Where(x => x.CollegeId == college.CollegeId)
                              .Select(x => new OurCourse()
                              {
                                 Name = x.Name,
                                 NumberOfYears = x.Years
                              }).ToList()
}
```